# Stripe.js and Laravel - Token not generated by Javascript or passed to server

Tags: php, laravel, stripe-payments

Query regarding stripe.js token. :)

I have a basic checkout set up. I'm using Laravel and Stripe.js to process payments. I have followed a guide but seem to be having trouble getting Stripe.js to generate and pass a token to the server.

Laravel Payment Form (validated with Parsley.js):

```
{!! Form::open(['url' => '/order/'.$order_info['script_id'].'/post', 'data-parsley-validate','id' => 'payment-form']) !!}

          <div class="form-group" id="first-name-group">
              {!! Form::label('firstName', 'First Name:') !!}
              {!! Form::text('first_name', null, [
                  'class'                         => 'form-control',
                  'required'                      => 'required',
                  'data-parsley-required-message' => 'First name is required',
                  'data-parsley-trigger'          => 'change focusout',
                  'data-parsley-pattern'          => '/^[a-zA-Z]*$/',
                  'data-parsley-minlength'        => '2',
                  'data-parsley-maxlength'        => '32',
                  'data-parsley-class-handler'    => '#first-name-group'
                  ]) !!}
          </div>

          <div class="form-group" id="last-name-group">
              {!! Form::label('lastName', 'Last Name:') !!}
              {!! Form::text('last_name', null, [
                  'class'                         => 'form-control',
                  'required'                      => 'required',
                  'data-parsley-required-message' => 'Last name is required',
                  'data-parsley-trigger'          => 'change focusout',
                  'data-parsley-pattern'          => '/^[a-zA-Z]*$/',
                  'data-parsley-minlength'        => '2',
                  'data-parsley-maxlength'        => '32',
                  'data-parsley-class-handler'    => '#last-name-group'
                  ]) !!}
          </div>

          <div class="form-group" id="email-group">
              {!! Form::label('email', 'Email address:') !!}
              {!! Form::email('email', null, [
                  'class' => 'form-control',
                  'placeholder'                   => 'email@example.com',
                  'required'                      => 'required',
                  'data-parsley-required-message' => 'Email name is required',
                  'data-parsley-trigger'          => 'change focusout',
                  'data-parsley-class-handler'    => '#email-group'
                  ]) !!}
          </div>


          <div class="form-group" id="cc-group">
              {!! Form::label(null, 'Credit card number:') !!}
              {!! Form::text(null, null, [
                  'class'                         => 'form-control ',
                  'id'                            => 'card-number',
                  'required'                      => 'required',
                  'data-parsley-type'             => 'number',
                  'maxlength'                     => '16',
                  'data-parsley-trigger'          => 'change focusout',
                  'data-parsley-class-handler'    => '#cc-group'
                  ]) !!}
          </div>

          <div class="form-group" id="ccv-group">
              {!! Form::label(null, 'Card Validation Code (3 or 4 digit number):') !!}
              {!! Form::text(null, null, [
                  'class'                         => 'form-control',
                  'id'                            => 'card-cvc',
                  'required'                      => 'required',
                  'data-parsley-type'             => 'number',
                  'data-parsley-trigger'          => 'change focusout',
                  'maxlength'                     => '4',
                  'data-parsley-class-handler'    => '#ccv-group'
                  ]) !!}
          </div>

          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4">
              <div class="form-group" id="exp-m-group">
                  {!! Form::label(null, 'Ex. Month') !!}
                  {!! Form::selectMonth(null, null, [
                      'class'                 => 'form-control',
                      'id'                    => 'card-expiry-month',
                      'required'              => 'required'
                  ], '%m') !!}
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
              <div class="form-group" id="exp-y-group">
                  {!! Form::label(null, 'Ex. Year') !!}
                  {!! Form::selectYear(null, date('Y'), date('Y') + 10, null, [
                      'class'             => 'form-control',
                      'id'                => 'card-expiry-year',
                      'required'          => 'required'
                      ]) !!}
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>



            <div class="form-group">
                {!! Form::submit('Place order!', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary btn-order', 'id' => 'submitBtn', 'style' => 'margin-bottom: 10px;']) !!}
            </div>

            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-12">
                  <span class="payment-errors" style="color: red;margin-top:10px;"></span>
              </div>
            </div>

        {!! Form::close() !!}
```

JS:

```
  <!-- Inlude Stripe.js -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://js.stripe.com/v2/"></script>
<script>
    // This identifies your website in the createToken call below
    Stripe.setPublishableKey('{!! env('STRIPE_PK') !!}');


    jQuery(function($) {
        $('#payment-form').submit(function(event) {
            var $form = $(this);

            // Before passing data to Stripe, trigger Parsley Client side validation
            $form.parsley().subscribe('parsley:form:validate', function(formInstance) {
                formInstance.submitEvent.preventDefault();
                return false;
            });

            // Disable the submit button to prevent repeated clicks
            $form.find('#submitBtn').prop('disabled', true);

           Stripe.card.createToken({
              number: $('#card-number').val(),
              cvc: $('#card-cvc').val(),
              exp_month: $('#card-expiry-month').val(),
              exp_year: $('#card-expiry-year').val()
            }, stripeResponseHandler);

            // Prevent the form from submitting with the default action
            return false;
        });
    });

    function stripeResponseHandler(status, response) {

        console.log(token); //outputs "undefined" to console

        var $form = $('#payment-form');

        if (response.error) {
            // Show the errors on the form
            $form.find('.payment-errors').text(response.error.message);
            $form.find('.payment-errors').addClass('alert alert-danger');
            $form.find('#submitBtn').prop('disabled', false);
            $('#submitBtn').button('reset');
        } else {
            // response contains id and card, which contains additional card details
            var token = response.id;


            // Insert the token into the form so it gets submitted to the server
            $form.append($('<input type="hidden" name="stripeToken" />').val(token));
            // and submit
            $form.get(0).submit();
        }
    };
</script>
```

Controller Action:

```
    public function postOrder(Request $request, $script_id){

    $validator = \Validator::make(\Input::all(), [
        'first_name' => 'required|string|min:2|max:32',
        'last_name' => 'required|string|min:2|max:32',
        'email' => 'required|email',
    ]);

    if ($validator->fails()) {
        return redirect()->back()
            ->withErrors($validator);
    }

    $token = $request->input('stripeToken');
    //dd($token);
    $first_name = $request->input('first_name');
    $last_name = $request->input('last_name');
    $email = $request->input('email');
    $price = $request->input['price'];
    $emailCheck = User::where('email', $email)->value('email');

    //dd($emailCheck);

    \Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey(env('STRIPE_SK'));

    // If the email doesn't exist in the database create new customer and user record
    if (!isset($emailCheck)) {
        // Create a new Stripe customer
        try {

            $customer = \Stripe\Customer::create([
            'source' => $token,
            'email' => $email,
            'metadata' => [
                "First Name" => $first_name,
                "Last Name" => $last_name
            ]
            ]);
        } catch (\Stripe\Error\Card $e) {
            return "fail";
        }
    }


       // dd(Auth::user()->stripe_customer_id);

        if(Auth::user()->stripe_customer_id == ""){
            $user = Auth::user();
            $user->stripe_customer_id = $customer->id;
            $user->save();
            $customerID = $customer->id;
        }

        else{
            $customerID = Auth::user()->stripe_customer_id;
        }

    // charge customer

     //   dd($customerID);

    try {
        $charge = \Stripe\Charge::create([
            'amount' => $price,
            'currency' => 'usd',
            'customer' => $customerID,
            'metadata' => [
                'product_name' => "Vidmaker Purchase"
            ]
            ]);

    } catch (\Stripe\Error\Card $e) {
       /* return redirect()->route('order')
            ->withErrors($e->getMessage())
            ->withInput();*/
            dd($e->getMessage());
    }

    Order::create([
        'user_id' => $user->id,
        'script_id' => $script_id,
        'amount' => $price,
        'stripe_transaction_id' => $charge->id,
    ]);

    /*return redirect()->route('order')
        ->with('successful', 'Your purchase was successful!');*/

        return "Success";


}
```

}

When I try use "stripeToken" on the server it is null - I checked it and it's not being passed in the POST method.

I've been tinkering with the JS for hours. I even have the card details printing out to the console find. But when passed into Stripe.card.createToken() no token is generated.

It proceeds to the server anyways and the Stripe::charge() action catches an error saying :

> "Cannot charge a customer that has no active card"

Anyone have any idea? I've spend a good six hours and at this point I'm truly stumped.

Cheers,
Dean

Comment: `console.log(token); //outputs "undefined" to console` - your calling `token` before your defining it with `var token = response.id;` so of course it will be  'undefined'.

Comment: Perhaps try `console.log(response)` first to see if it has an `id` attribute defined...

Comment: Oh damn - didn't notice that! Thanks. The response prints out with an id field populated with a token. Here it is: Object {id: "tok_18HM1O2vcUPnlOr23yR51x2q", object: "token", card: Object, client_ip: "109.255.124.237", created: 1464736298…}      So perhaps the issue lies elsewhere? Or it's not sending to the server?

Comment: The next step would be to confirm that this line: `$form.append($('<input type="hidden" name="stripeToken" />').val(token));` is working correctly. Try commenting out the last line `$form.get(0).submit();` which should stop the form from actually submitting so that you can check if the previous line worked and actually inserted the hidden input into the form - makes sense?

Comment: Yup - it's attaching to the form alright. I did a dd($token) on their server-side and the token is printing out now just fine. It might have been  a cache issue.... However, I'm still getting the "Cannot charge a customer that has no active card" error when trying to charge. So I'm thinking that there must be an issue with the Laravel code now.

Comment: can you post the code in question?

Comment: Edited original. In there now. Thank you. I really appreciate it. Everything works fine and $token dd()s out to a valid token string now. However when it gets down to making a new charge it fails.

Comment: My hunch now is that it's to do with the customer id but I can't figure out where it's going wrong. Perhaps it's never actually using a valid Stripe customer?

Comment: what do you get when you run `dd($customerID);`?

Comment: Also, this line: `$emailCheck = User::where('email', $email)->value('email');` doesn't look right, try changing it to `$emailCheck = User::where('email', $email)->pluck('email');`.

Comment: Figured it out with your help! :) Basically I was seeing if a user had a stripe ID. If they didn't then I made a new Stripe customer and saved the id of that new customer in the db and processed the transaction. However if they did  already have a stripe_customer_id stored in the db (whichmy test account did all along) it skipped the crucial step of creating a stripe customer object and instead just assigned their customer id alone (no token, details etc...). Got it working. Thank you very much! :)